# Mongo reverse regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, reverse

In SQL it is possible to run a query similar to

```
SELECT result FROM table WHERE 'abc-def-ghi' LIKE col1
```

on a table like this:

```
col1      | result
abc-%     | 1
abc-d%    | 2
as%       | 3
...       | ...
```

and get a result set with 1 and 2.

Problem: how do I achieve same effect in mongodb?
I can run regex to match against fields but is there a way that the fields could be match agains supplied data?

Comment: mongodb doesn't currently have that feature.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $where operator, e.g.:

```
db.col.find({$where: "\"abc\".match(this.col1)"})
```

Although MongoDB documentation doesn't recommend using $where, it is the only possibility as far as I know.

(This question is probably a duplicate. See [MongoDB reverse regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966991/mongodb-reverse-regex))

Comment: BTW a ticket is opened in MongoDB JIRA about this improvement https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13902

Answer (score -3):

```
db.stuff.find( { col1 : /supplied_data/ }, { result : 1 } );
```

Will return only the result field.