# MongoDB reverse regex

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a document in MongoDB with a regex attribute

```
    {
        _id: ObjectId("516023189732da20ce000004"),
        regex: /^(my|your)\s+regex$/
    }
```

and I need to retrieve this document with something like `db.col.find({regex: 'your regex'})` and `db.col.find({regex: 'my regex'})`.
In MySQL I'd do: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'my regex' REGEXP table.regex`. How can I achieve this in MongoDB?

Comment: hnmm maybe I am missing something but doesn't: `db.col.find({regex: '/^[my|your]\s+regex$/'})` work since it isn't outisde of quotes and it isn't a regexp object?

Comment: This seems to be a perl(ish) regex. This means this will not match to `my regex` or `your regex`, but `m regex` or `y regex` or `| regex` &c. If it had to match with `my regex` it would be `/^(my|your)\s+regex$/`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TrueY you're right, I used the wrong parenthesis.

Comment: @Sammaye I need to match a string against a regex object attribute.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the $where operator in the following fashion:

```
db.col.find({$where: "\"my regex\".match(this.regex)"})
```

Comment: Although pretty slow, it works, thank you! But it matches also documents where `this.regex` is not defined, so I think I'm going to define a function instead of the expression.

Comment: I'm afraid that using $where is always slow, MongoDB documentation discourages using it... I also would like to know about quicker ways :) Of course, you can use a JavaScript function for the $where value to deal with edge cases such as not defined fields, etc.

Comment: BTW a ticket is opened in MongoDB JIRA about this improvement https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13902

Answer (score 4):

As explained into [Jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13902) provided by [@fgalan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485926/fgalan) on 2013, you can use `$expr` you can use this query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$regexMatch": {
      "input": "$key",
      "regex": "$regex",
      "options": "i"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1a6spSvU8_Q)

With `$expr` you can avoid `$where` which is not efficient.