# Matching string to regex id using MongoDB and pymongo

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I have a very large [csv](http://browscap.org) that I'm trying to search through.  I've decided to use MongoDB and load in the whole csv so I can quickly search through it later with python and pymongo, instead of having to load all 80MB each time I try a search. What I can't figure out, is how to search through the collection for a given user agent and match it to the regex that is in the item's '_id' field.  I first process the browscap entry to a python rege, then insert the item into the mongo collection.

How do I search with pymongo a given user agent for a regex mongoID?

Example User Agent:

> AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.12B440 (iPad; U; CPU OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X; en_us)

Example Browscap Entry:

> AppleCoreMedia/1.0* (iPhone*CPU OS 8* like Mac OS X*)*

Example Regex Mongo ID:

> ^AppleCoreMedia\/1\\.0.\*?\\ \\(iPhone.*?CPU\\ OS\\ 8.*?\\ like\\ Mac\\ OS\\ X.*?\\).*?$

Comment: What are you saying here? Is the "regex" itself the string stored in the `_id`? Or is just the user agent string stored in the `_id` and you want to search with a regex? For the former case you need the `$where` evalution as mentioned in [MongoDB reverse regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966991/mongodb-reverse-regex). Thought it's notably not a good performer, and you might want to rethink what you are doing here if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Agent would be a poor choice for the _id field due to low entropy.

Aside from that, the fact that _id gets indexed should result in mongoDB storing most/all of the data in memory anyway.

Comment: But the regex'd id is what is indexed.  I don't know what the actual User Agent is until I have a search to do.