# get all documents with its value contained in given string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am given string "the Google" or "Google Canada" or "Google pvt ltd" I have Mongodb collection with each document containing a name like Google in this case.

I want all the documents which have any substring of the given string. How do I do it in mangodb?

If I search for Google Canada

```
 db.merchant.find({name:{$regex:"Google Canada", $options:"$i"}})
```

I should get

```
{
  "_id": "5731a3aaefa070225623e4d3",
  "name": "GOOGLE"
}
{
  "_id": "5731a3aaefa070225623e4d3",
  "name": "CANADA"
}    {
  "_id": "5731a3aaefa070225623e4d3",
  "name": "CANA"
}
```

Comment: You need to "reverse" your regex lookup, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966991/mongodb-reverse-regex

Answer (score 0):

just refer text indexes in mongodb .
 its help to you . 
it will provide this type of search also

see this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simplest method of using regex to get all documents based on name in mongodb :

db.collection.find({name:{$regex:"Google",$options:"$i"}})

Here $i is used to make the search case insensitive.