# Mongodb use regex expressions on field value

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, find, version

I have this document collection:

```
{
    _id: 3,
    version: "v1_8_R2"
}, 
{
    _id: 2,
    version: "v1_8"
}
{
    _id: 1,
    version: "v1_8_R3"
}
```

Using `db.coll.find({version:"v1_8_R3"})` I get the `id: 1` document, but `id: 2` is compatible with the `v1_8_R3` version and the `id: 1` is outdated, and I don't want `v1_8_R2` to be matched since it's incompatible with `v1_8_R3`

With regex I could solve that, but mongo doesn't allow to use it in fields unlike mysql

This works, but the other way around: `db.coll.find(version: {$regex: "v1_8_R3", $options: "i"})`

I would need something like this: `db.coll.find({$regex: version, $options: "i"}: "v1_8_R3")`

Then it would match v1_8, and wouldn't match v1_8_R2

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966991/mongodb-reverse-regex

Comment: @JohnnyHK it has the regex inside the document. I don't

Comment: I thought you were looking to use the docs' `version` as a regex?

Comment: Let me test something, that gave me an idea

Comment: I do not understand what the goal is. If you want to match `v1_8` and `v1_8_R3`, you may use a `"^v1_8(?:_R3)?$"` regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm making a package system for a platform, that has different versions, some plugins can run on all versions, some are version dependent, and I think I solved it but it's not an efficient way