# Match against regex pattern stored in field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

This question is regarding query capabilities of MongoDB to match a regex that is stored in a field.

In the database I am storing simple postcode regex patterns. For example in the zipcode field: `3121, 312*, 313?`

Then if someone inputs any string that matches any of the patterns that record should be returned. So user would input one of: "3121", "31222", "3135" and the record should match and be returned. It's kind of the inverse of a normal regex match.

I know I could test every zipcode match individually in code, but is it possible to construct a mongoDB query to handle the match directly?

What would I put in this query?

`db.shippingZones.query({}).pretty()`

As an example, the `shippingzone` document would look like:

```
{
  id: 123455678,
  states: ['NSW', 'VIC'],
  zipcodes: ['3121', '312*', '313?']
}
```

Then when the user inputs '31222' I need a query that will return the sample document because the regex 312* matches.

Comment: Have you tried [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) ?

Comment: I am not sure how to use $regex in this case. My understanding of it is it would match if I was entering the regex pattern. But I'm not, I"m entering the value and want to test it for a match against a field containing an array of regex patterns...

Comment: So `3121, 312*, 313?` are field names?

Comment: nope, they're values in the field, doc would be like:  {id: 12342134, states: ['NSW', 'VIC'], zipcodes: ['3121', '312*', '313?']}

Comment: Can you update your question with db structure?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966991/mongodb-reverse-regex

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from an answer by [J.F. on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69979596/13398050)

Use the following aggregation pipeline:

- `$unwind`    break down the `zipcodes` array into individual elements
- `$regexMatch`    match the input with the value of `zipcodes` in each document
- `$group`     group the results to reconstruct the original document back

A more complex aggregation pipeline (to preserve all `zipcodes`)

- `$addFields`  copy the `zipcodes` array to another field `copyZipCodes`
- `$unwind`    break down the `copyZipCodes` array into individual elements
- `$regexMatch`    match the input with the value of `copyZipCodes` in each document
- `$group`     group the results to obtain the original document back

The pipeline

```
db.shippingZones.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "copyZipCodes": "$zipcodes"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$copyZipCodes"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$regexMatch": {
          "input": "31222",
          "regex": "$copyZipCodes"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "id": {
        "$first": "$id"
      },
      "states": {
        "$first": "$states"
      },
      "zipcodes": {
        "$first": "$zipcodes"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Link to [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9aPqDSSOtpI)