# MongoDB reverse regex -> db.col.find({$where: "\"my regex\".match(this.regex)"}) if this.regex is array of regex strings

Tags: mongodb

I have a similar problem like Giovanni in this post: [MongoDB reverse regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966991/mongodb-reverse-regex)

Unlike his request I have an array of regex strings in my db which I would like to query the same way. The solution provided for Giovanni works fine on a field with type string, but isn't working on an array of strings.

The regex array inside my db has the following form:

```
"regex": [
       "test_.*?_reg",
       ".*?_hello_world"
],
```

test_123_reg should match, test-123-reg should not match. Same for the second and every other entry. "regex" is one field inside one Document.

This is the right solution for string type:

```
$where: "\"test_123_reg\".match(this.regex)"
```

Manny thanks in advance for your help.