# Mongodb reverse match API endpoint path

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, typescript

Trying to set up a webhook system where the user can hook into any method of my express server by providing a method and an endpoint to listen to (eg `PUT /movies/*`). This would send the edited movie to the user's callback url.

The challenges I'm facing here are:

1. Not forcing the user to write a full-on regular expression (something like bash wildcards would be ideal, or the way node `path-to-regexp` library works)
2. Retrieving all the hooks matching an endpoint when it is called

I'm really not sure how to deal with the first point, however I was able retrieve my webhooks using the solution provided here [MongoDB reverse regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966991/mongodb-reverse-regex)

```js
  private static async getWebhooks(endpoint: string, method: string): Promise<any[]> {
    return await MongoDb.Instance.Models.Webhook.find({
      $where: `"${endpoint}".match(this.endpoint)`,
      method: method,
    });
  }
```

This doesn't exactly work as expected. Provided `GET /movies/*` this matches both the `GET /movies` and the `GET /movies/:movieId` endpoints when it should only match the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm just lacking sleep, I've approached this the wrong way.

One solution would be to just call the `path-to-regexp` method on the endpoint provided by the user when registering the webhook, that way a true expression would be stored alongside the endpoint but hidden to the user.

```js
import * as pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';  

public async Create(webhook: IWebhook): Promise<any> {
  let pattern = pathToRegexp(webhook.endpoint.original, []);
  webhook.endpoint.pattern = pattern;

  const createdWebhook = await MongoDb.Instance.Models.Webhook.create(webhook);

  this.setStatus(201);
  return createdWebhook;
}
```