# $expr with $regexMatch doesn't work when the pattern is inside an array

Tags: regex, mongodb

Based in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69979596/1485926), I'm using `$expr` and `$regexMatch` to implement "reverse regex" queries in MongoDB. For instance [this example works](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ibWLonDkxFT)

However, this only seems to work when the regex is in a first level field in the MongoDB document. In the case the regex is within an element in an array (as in [this other example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IeXsLOrU7LD) I get errors like this:

```
query failed: (Location51105) Executor error during find command :: caused by :: $regexMatch needs 'regex' to be of type string or regex
```

Is there any way of supporting this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `regex` allows only string input, You can use `$map` operator to loop the array elements and check the condition,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `patterns.pattern` array and check `$regexMatch` condition, it will return boolean value
- `$anyElementTrue` to check if any element is true then it will true

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$anyElementTrue": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$patterns.pattern",
        "in": {
          "$regexMatch": {
            "input": "Room1",
            "regex": "$$this",
            "options": "i"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2bb8aC45kJS)